# Add Google Analytics Tracking to Dynamics CRM Install

Tags: google-analytics, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

I'd like to add Google Analytics tracking script to all page loads in Dynamics CRM - so I can track and analyze how people work in the app and find pain-points with our processes.

I modified the tracking script to pull the userID (GUID) and entity ID (GUID) and put them into custom dimensions. I expect to use that to determine the user viewing the site, form name, entity name, etc. in my reports. I also set it up to

However, our developer says the best way to do this is to manually add the script to every entity (or something like that - but it's a manual thing done to every single entity). I feel like it's a web page... so it should be able to just have some javascript in the header like anything else.

Is there a better way? Any ideas? I don't want it to be hacky - this is for a production/enterprise system... Obviously I'm not very familiar with Dynamics in this light... Just looking for some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the script is a piece of JavaScript you want to run on page load. Then adding the script to every page isn't just the best way to do this, but the only *supported* way to do this. Microsoft make available a number of ways to extend and customise CRM, unfortunately they don't just allow you to do anything you like.

So whilst CRM is just a bunch of web pages, they aren't your web pages to edit freely. Microsoft provide a number of extensible points but direct editing of the DOM isn't one of them.

I suppose a good simile here is that StackOverflow allow me to type any answer I like, but then don't allow me to change the font. Whilst this is a web page I can edit, it's not my web page.

That all said its worth bearing in mind what supported actually means. Something which is unsupported typically means:

- What you want to do probably won't work easily.
- If you do get it to work, the next update of CRM will probably break it.
- Microsoft might not feel so obliged to help when it does break.

You may find [Supported extensions for Microsoft Dynamics CRM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328350.aspx) useful.

In terms of what you do to make this work:

- You could try hacking open the installed server files to find somewhere to add your script. However I would advise against this as its not supported (I advise against anything unsupported).
- Your you can write the script once in a web resource, and use on every page. The only duplication required is to add the event handlers to each form, which is relatively quick for a single form.
- Your users probably aren't using every page (and you can't add script to every page anyway, only forms) so just target the pages you need rather than trying to get 100% coverage.
- CRM has a set of meta data web services you can use to create fields and entities. Perhaps you could use it to perform form edits and automate the process.

If you are looking to analyse system performance then perhaps adding form script isn't the best way to do it anyway. Tracking client form interactions only really scratches the surface of CRM usage anyway. What about plugins, workflows, data base, and web services which all execute server side but affect client performance?

Perhaps broaden your searches to include topics such as CRM monitoring, optimization and management. For example; [Optimizing and Maintaining Client Performance for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 and Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204512(v=crm.6).aspx).